# Unable to compile to C

Tags: compile

I used to be able to compile to C without problems, but from one day to the next, when I try to compile something, e.g.

```
Compile[{{x,_Real}},x^2,CompilationTarget->"C"]
```

I get the message

```
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function.
```

I searched for the error message but can't find out what's going on.

Comment: Do you **always** get the `Compile::nogen` error? Or only some of the time?

Comment: Since a few days always, before I never got it.

Comment: Works for me with 10.0.1 on Mac OSX.  Did you recently update? What's your platform?

Comment: I have mathematica 10.0 and also on Mac OSX. I didn't manually update anything, don't know about auto updates though.

Comment: If you're a mac user, there was a patch for XCODE and 10.9.5 last week I think which meant I had to run the XCODE installer again on SystemModeler to bring that back to life with compiling.... wonder if it's the same issue?  Try running XCODE, then rerunning in Mathematica maybe?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped... not sure if this is classed as an answer or not in all honesty as it's technically not a Mathematica solution, either way I'm pleased it worked.

Comment: I too hav some doubts.......plz explain properly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the 10.9.5 patch to MacOS and the corresponding update to XCODE it may be necessary to run XCODE again to reinstall it and then this should renable C compilation in Mathematica (v10) and SystemModeler (v3).

Certainly was the case for me.